# Passing const& as a function argument

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Could there be any problem with passing `const &` as an argument to a function?

Recently we have rewritten all occurrences of an object passing by value to pass by reference `&` or by `const &` when applicable.

There were no compiler errors.

The application is a windows service and its unable to start. We don't have a debug version and so I am here to ask.

Comment: It depends.  I would suggest you create a debug version, and debug the problem.

Comment: If previously you passed everything by value. And you just changed them to references then they should all be changed to `const&` otherwise you will change what the code is doing. If any method is modifying a parameter then it needs to make a local copy not modify the original (otherwise you are changing the meaning of the code).

Comment: Why are you making this change?  If you have `void func(int param)`, you can change it to `void func(const int &param)`, but what does it gain you?

Answer (score 0):

So, one way your application behavior could have changed is: if you blindly pass something by `&` that was previously passed by value, modify it's state and the old code did not expect that state change to happen and assumes that the object that was passed to the function is still in the state it used to be before it was passed.

Passing by `&` is what can cause trouble and not `const&`. Unless... grep the codebase for `const_cast`.

Comment: You don't need a `const_cast` for this.  Consider a class that contains a pointer member.  Making the object `const` doesn't protect the thing being pointed to.

Comment: Making the class instance `const` effectively makes all members `const`, so a class member of the form `int *my_ptr` effectively becomes `int *const my_ptr`.  But that's distinct from `const int *my_ptr`.