# passing values in a function that returns a struct - const errors

Tags: c++, struct, constants

I spent around two hours on that problem, and I have visited these stackoverflow questions before:

[c++ passing a const object reference to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327437/c-passing-a-const-object-reference-to-a-function)

[Passing const& as a function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638985/passing-const-as-a-function-argument)

both did not help me, so I am specifying my problem here:

1) I have a class `Polygon` that stores `Point2D`s in a list. The class has among others two member functions:

```
public:    
  std::pair<Point2D,Point2D> closestPts()  const;
private:
  Tripel const& findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P,
                                std::vector<Point2D> const& X,
                                std::vector<Point2D> const& Y) const;
```

2) The class also contains a `struct Triple` that is the return value of the function `findClosestPts`. I need that, because the function needs to return two points and one distance:

```
struct Tripel {
  Point2D pt1;
  Point2D pt2;
  float   dist;
};
```

The problem is now in the implementation of Polygon.cpp. This is my (current) code for the two above mentioned functions:

```
std::pair<Point2D,Point2D> Polygon::closestPts() const {
   ...
   int size = m_points.size();
   std::vector<Point2D> P (size);
   std::vector<Point2D> X (size);
   std::vector<Point2D> Y (size);
   ...
   // some manipulation of the vectors, filling them with Point2D
   // at this point, I have three non-const std::vector<Point2D>

   // try to call the other function       
   Tripel closPts = findClosestPts(P, X, Y);
   ...
}

Tripel const& findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P, std::vector<Point2D> const& X, std::vector<Point2D> const& Y) const {
   ...
}
```

The compiler error is:

```
error: non-member function 'const Tripel& findClosestPts(...)' cannot have cv-qualifier
```

So I guess I am not allowed to make this function `const`, because it returns a `struct`. Is that true?

Anyways, I changed the function signature to this:

```
Tripel const& findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P,
                              std::vector<Point2D> const& X,
                              std::vector<Point2D> const& Y);
```

So, the function is not `const` anymore. This leads to the following compiling error:

```
error: passing 'const Polygon' as 'this' argument of 'const Tripel& Polygon::findClosestPts(...)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I do not know, what to do now. I tried pretty much everything, deleting all the const statements, changing them around, making `findClosestPts` public, making it const again, making the three std::vectors const before passing them into the other function ... but everything leaded to (different) compiling errors.

So my question is, how do I need to write the two functions, to achieve the following: I want to have a function `closestPoints()` that is a public member function and that returns the pair of the two closest points. For that it needs an auxilary, private member function `findClosestPts(vector1, vector2, vector3)` that returns the above mentioned `struct Triple`?

I would be happy about help, because I am stucked here since a while :/

Comment: Are you sure you want to return a const reference? This could easily lead to a dangling reference. `Triple` seems to be a value type anyway.

Comment: Confusion: Is `Triple` === `Tripel` ?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm pretty sure they mean the same? English vs. German. ;-)

Comment: oh yeah... that was a typo ;) And yes, you guessed my nationality correctly :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **can** make it `const`, you just forgot to qualify the name in the implementation.

```
          //class name
                ||
                \/
Tripel const& Polygon::findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P, 
           std::vector<Point2D> const& X, std::vector<Point2D> const& Y) const
```

Comment: Bloody hell that was quick typing, I thought I was pretty fast

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in the error message:

```
error: non-member function ...
```

At that point you can stop reading, because your compiler thinks your function is a *non-member* function. Any further text on that line is based on your compiler making an incorrect conclusion (based on what you wanted). The solution is to add the `Polygon::` qualifier to your member function implementation:

```
Tripel const& Polygon::findClosestPts( ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to qualify the function name with the class name like

```
Tripel const& Polygon::findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P, std::vector<Point2D> const& X, std::vector<Point2D> const& Y) const
```

Luchian beat me to it but the error tells you that **Non-member** cannot have cv qualifier, for the same reason that static functions cannot be cv qualified

Answer (score 0):

Please note you'd better return here:

```
Tripel const& findClosestPts (std::vector<Point2D> const& P,  
                                std::vector<Point2D> const& X,
                                std::vector<Point2D> const& Y) const;
```

the value of Tripel, not the reference to it.
As someone noted already, this is not safe to return a reference.

Such functions almost always must return a value, not a reference, 
as otherwise you will need to keep lifetime of the object returning the reference with lifetime of object/code accepting the reference in correspondence. That is, lifetime of the returning object must be kept within of lifetime of receiving object or code.

Comment: but one more question: Should I now return it `const` or just like that?

Comment: If you return an object by value, this is always a temporary object and it does not matter if it is CONST or not (or any other modifier like volatile etc), because the object cannot be actually reused, it fully belongs to the accepting code, so there is no need to restrict anything here.

~ 90% of code in C++ return objects by value without modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... this would have not been worth all that work... I simply forgot the class qualifier `Polygon::` That is really embarrassing, I am sorry :(

Thank you all for your help, I think the problem is solved!